# Invite friend who does not own the game to a GKTurnBasedMatch

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

In my game I am trying to allow the user to start a turn based a match with a friend. I display the friends to the user in a table and the user picks one. Once the user picks a friend the game is started and the user takes their first turn. When the selected friend has the game installed then everything works. If the friend does not have the game installed the match ends and the GKTurnBasedParticipant status is Declined.

This is the code to create the match.

```
        GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
        request.minPlayers = 2;
        request.maxPlayers = 2;
        request.playersToInvite = @[playerId]; // this is the player id selected from the friends table

        [GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil && match != nil){
                [self startNewMatch:match];
            }
        }];
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create 2 test users in iTunes Connect
2. On Device 1 (not simulator) open game and sign in to Game Centre
3. On Device 2 (not simulator) open Game Centre and sign in
4. On Device 1 send friend request to account that is on Device 2
5. On Device 2 accept friendship
6. On Device 1 start a game and play first turn.

Expected: Match is waiting for device 2 to take turn.

Actual: Match has ended with status GKTurnBasedMatchStatusEnded and Device 2 GKTurnBasedParticipant has status Declined.

To make things more interesting if Device 2 is the simulator than the match goes into the correct state.